# @PostLoad and @PrePersist in Spring Data JDBC project

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

Does Spring Data JDBC have anything similar to `@PostLoad` and `@PrePersist` from Spring Data JPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Spring Data JDBC you currently can't annotate the entity directly. But there are [life cycle listeners](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.events) and [callbacks](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.entity-callbacks) that you can use for the same purpose.

One of the examples given:

```java
@Component
class UserCallbacks implements BeforeConvertCallback<User>,
                                        BeforeSaveCallback<User> {   

    @Override
    public Person onBeforeConvert(User user) {
        return // ...
    }

    @Override
    public Person onBeforeSave(User user) {
        return // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. 

One suggestion regarding the documentation: please add an expand/collapse button next to each chapter name in the documentation (table of contents). 

Since the Preface chapter was expanded by default, I haven't noticed other chapters were expandable.